We need more questions / Abbiamo bisogno di più domande
Aggiornamento / Edit (Charo):
Cerco di riaprire questo dibattito perché questo sito è meraviglioso, ma sono anche dell'opinione che
abbiamo bisogno di un po' più di domande, fatte da più utenti diversi, in particolare, fatte anche da italiani per farlo diventare ancora più interessante. In questa risposta su Meta si può vedere come il numero di risposte nel 2019 è cresciuto rispetto a quello del 2018, e questo è un fatto positivo. Però la quantità di domande è invece discesa. Per di più, siamo alla fine del mese (febbraio 2020) e, a giudicare dai voti, in tutto questo mese si sono fatte appena tre domande minimamente interessanti. Quindi, abbiamo soprattutto bisogno di domande interessanti e sono sicura che ce ne sono ancora molte da fare. Cercherò io stessa di aggiungere qualcosa come risposta a questo post.

I was recently perusing the Area 51 analytics for this site and I was struck but just how few questions we have. In particular I have asked no questions, and I am not the only active user to have done so. Sometimes I feel that if it weren't for Charo, this site would be dead (thanks!) The problem is, I cannot come up with any good "type" of questions I would like to ask. So I decided to ask the community for ideas.

What are "templates" for good questions to ask in this site, especially for questions asked by native speakers?

Let me get the ball rolling with a couple of (weak) suggestions:

Etymologies and origin of idiomatic expressions / Etimologie e origini di espressioni idiomatiche
There just aren't any good online resources for etymologies in Italian, so if you do not have an etymological dictionary near you (for example because you do not live in Italy) you are stuck. The situation may be even worse if you look for the origin of some Italian idiom or expression because for etymologies of words you can at least find some information in standard monolingual dictionaries.
It is then natural to ask for questions here.

Consecutio temporum / Concordanza dei tempi
Sometimes it is just hard to decide which tense to use. Some of these questions may be specially hard, as this one, because they cannot be easily solved using online resources. This kind of things can also be asked  by Italians when they are found in the situation that they know what tense to use but they don't know how to explain why.
Ask it here!

I agree that 0,9 questions/day is something poor. I personally asked for just only a question and I'm concerned about the situation. And obviously I propose @Charo as permanent lifetime gold level moderator :))

Now we have reached 3 questions/day: it's the first time I have seen this on Italian.SE! Nevertheless, my impression now is that we need more people participating actively doing other things: writing answers and comments; voting questions, answers and comments; reviewing posts...

Regional Italian / Italiano regionale
I'm not referring to the different languages or the so called "dialects" spoken in Italy,  but rather to the esistence of differences in the way Italian is spoken in different regions of Italy. There can be differences in pronunciation, vocabulary and use of grammatical structures. This makes the language richer and, in my opinion, it would be interesting to learn more about these regional differences. To make an example in my own language (Catalan), it was exciting to me to discover someone from Mallorca asking for a "gelat de fraula" where I would have said "gelat de maduixa" (the meaning of this expression is "strawberry ice cream").

Personalmente, mi rattrista che qualcuno pensi che l'italiano regionale sia un tema completamente inadatto per porre domande su questo sito (ma rispetto questa e tutte le opinioni).

Questo esempio di domanda su Spanish.SE è su un regionalismo. Per di più, si chiede su una parola di uso colloquiale e si tratta di una domanda (ben accetta) con auto-risposta. Quindi, mi sembra sia un buon esempio per parecchie delle proposte fatte qui nelle risposte. La domanda e la risposta sono in inglese, quindi si possono capire bene.

Non c'è dubbio che esistono differenze a livello regionale e domande su un termine od una frase usati in una regione sono sicuramente domande accettabili. Eviterei domande su una parola che è il calco di una parola dialettale, comunque, come una domanda che chieda perché a Brescia dicono "staradesso" al posto di "stantio".

Idioms
Explaining what they mean and in which context they are used. This topic is related to @Charo's regional Italian, since there may be changes between regions for the same concept.

Word/expression translation
Sometimes users of this forum complained that it is not a automatic translation site, but it is true that for foreign people could be hard to understand if a form of a word or expression is suitable in certain context. On this we could stretch a point.

We are doing fine.
I disagree with your premise. 0.9, or 1.3, or 3 questions per day is not bad. I am fine with Italian.SE being a site that I don't have to check daily to keep up with all the updates. Don't let SE guilt-trip you into thinking that there is something wrong in not having a super-high-traffic site. They only care about getting more users, but that is not necessarily also our goal as users.
I suggest that we do not insist on having more questions, especially if that implies that they are going to be artificial, lower-quality question of little interest to anybody.
(I gave a similar answer on another meta site.)

Non sono d'accordo e non è tanto un problema di quante domande al giorno abbiamo. È che troverei un sito con un po' più di partecipazione più interessante.

@Charo Se il problema è la partecipazione, secondo me abbiamo bisogno di più utenti, non di più domande dalle solite persone.

@FedericoPoloni A mio avviso, il problema è proprio una sorta di monopolizzazione abbastanza evidente.

@Nico: È la seconda volta che leggo questo in un tuo commento. Ti prego di porre una domanda su Meta in modo che possa essere discusso in profondità.

@charo Non mi pare ci sia bisogno di domande ulteriori. Come scrive Federico in "self-answers" per molti versi questo è diventato un sito in cui poche persone (tu in prima linea) "se la suonano e se la cantano". Porre una domanda a questo riguardo equivarrebbbe a un autodafé pubblico che non corrisponde al mio modo di concepire il dialogo. Se ho qualcosa da dirti, lo faccio direttamente come in questa risposta senza farne un affare di stato.

@FedericoPoloni: In realtà, concordo con te poiché, quando dico "più domande" voglio dire "più domande fatte da più utenti".

@Nico: Io invece credo che, se davvero pensi che il sito abbia un determinato problema, la cosa più costruttiva da fare sia di porre una domanda su Meta in modo che la comunità possa discutere sul problema e cercare delle soluzioni.

@Charo Il problema per me è che tu monopolizzi il sito e che lo usi per porre domande su temi peculiari che interessano a pochi invece di porre domande generali che potrebbero dare un consiglio a una non madrelingua che padroneggia l'italiano bene, ma che mostra parecchie lacune. Detta palese palese, tu sei come una che ha appena imparato a fare equazioni e pretende spiegazioni sulla teoria di Enistein. Ci sono altri punti salienti che sminuzzerò in seguito in caso di interesse.

Per favore, @Nico: scrivi una risposta a questa domanda su Meta spiegando quali sono queste domande generali che credi valga la pena porre. Infatti, questo è precisamente l'obiettivo di questa domanda su Meta: proporre domande che si possano fare su Italian.SE. In quanto alle mie lacune, sarebbe di gran aiuto per me sapere quali sono.

@Charo Mi spiace, ma ho l'impressione che tu non abbia capito la mia risposta...

@Nico Per favore modera i toni. Puoi formulare le obiezioni ad un certo tipo di domande senza offendere nessuno. Inoltre il senso del tuo commento non è chiaro neanche a me, per cui una domanda su meta in cui spieghi meglio cosa vuoi dire non sarebbe una cattiva idea.

@DenisNardin Quali toni? Dimostrazione di "offesa"? Mi spiace, ma io non vedo nessunissima offesa. Se esprimere la propria opinione schiettamente significa "offendere" siamo su due pianeti diversi.

Tu stesso l'hai detto, @Nico: non ho capito nulla. Ma riempire questa risposta con commenti che non hanno niente a che vedere non è il modo adatto di dare più dettagli. Ed è per questo che, come ha detto anche Denis, insisto sul fatto che dovresti farlo ponendo una domanda su Meta spiegando in dettaglio qual è il problema che hai menzionato qui.

@Charo Io non ho scritto che "non (hai) capito nulla", ma che non "hai capito la mia risposta". C'è una bella differenza...

Bene, @Nico, scusa: non ho capito il tuo commento che comincia così: "Il problema per me è che tu...".

@Charo Visto che sono stato accusato di essere offensivo, mi asterrò dal commentare questioni bollenti ulteriormente sia qui sia sul sito linguistico. Non è certo da me voler perturbare l'armonia regnante...

Vorrei soltanto aggiungere che, si qualcuno se ne accorge che una domanda può resultare interessante o utile soltanto a pochissime persone in tutto il pianeta, quello che si deve fare è votare per chiudere la domanda come "off-topic".

@Charo io chiedo meno estremismo: il problema non è una domanda (o una risposta) con determinate caratteristiche. Il problema è molte domande con una certa caratteristica. Senza voler offendere, ti prego capiscimi, chiedere alcune volte "che significa X in questo contesto?" è una cosa accettabile. Però se il 30% o più delle domande recenti è di quello stesso tipo, la cosa balza all'occhio. Se poi la stessa autrice di quel genere di domande dice che servono più domande e più risposte, viene un dubbio...

...il dubbio che tu voglia incrementare il traffico con domande diciamo poco sincere. Se però sono sincere, allora ti dico: cercati da te la risposta, lo sai fare meglio di me e lo dimostri quando ti rispondi da sola - io non voglio essere il tuo motore di ricerca. Sono contento di aiutarti ma preferisco darti qualche cosa di mio, non una citazione.

Mi accodo a questa risposta perché sono sostanzialmente d'accordo. Le altre proposte (frasi idiomatiche, regionalismi, auto-risposte) vanno benissimo, ma il vero fatto è che questo sito non ha in assoluto molto traffico. Purtroppo non so come lo si possa aumentare: pubblicità a pagamento su altri siti? passaparola di qualche tipo? Non ho idea, sono del tutto ignorante su come si faccia pubblicità in senso lato (non solo commerciale), e in genere ad attirare l'attenzione del pubblico su un'iniziativa interessante.

@DaG: Ho votato il tuo commento perché mi sembra un'idea sensata (negli ultimi giorni ho avuto una forte sensazione che abbiamo anche bisogno di idee sensate, ma anche su questo posso essere completamente sbagliata), benché, come ho espresso nel mio primo commento qui, non sia pienamente d'accordo (sparisco di nuovo).

Questions with self-answer / Domande con auto-risposta
Questa domanda di @DaG (e anche la sua risposta) è un buon esempio di quello che voglio dire. Vorrei rammentarvi che l'obiettivo di questo sito non è unicamente quello di dare l'opportunità alle persone di chiedere sui loro dubbi sull'italiano. È anche quello di condividere con altri utenti informazioni sulla lingua organizzate in forma di domande e risposte. Come nell'esempio di @DaG, possiamo avere un dubbio o vedere che qualcun altro ha un dubbio e trovare la risposta su un libro e allora è interessante condividerla con la comunità. Ma anche quando la sorgente o le sorgenti si trovano su Internet può a volte essere interessante scrivere un'auto-risposta, perché no? Non soltanto per il fatto che alcune fonti siano difficili da individuare, ma semplicemente perché organizzare certe informazioni in modo domanda-risposta può diventare utile a altre persone. Inoltre, può succedere che altri utenti aggiungano ulteriori risposte alla domanda, arricchendo così la informazione che si ha su un certo argomento.
Ecco un esempio di domanda con auto-risposta di @NicolaSap che penso illustri bene a cosa mi voglio riferire.
Possiamo anche adoperare le auto-risposte di tanto in tanto per condividere con la comunità fatti riguardanti la lingua italiana che abbiamo imparato e che ci sembrino interessanti o curiosi: qualcosa che abbiamo letto su un libro, ma anche, come ho detto prima, informazioni che abbiamo trovato su Internet. Non è che uno si metta tutti i giorni a leggere un dizionario tutto completo e poi pensi: dopo aver finito la mia lettura, questo e quest'altro mi sono sembrati fatti curiosi che non conoscevo. Per esempio, se uno non sente la necessità di cercare il lemma "scarlatto" sul Grande dizionario della lingua italiana probabilmente non se n'accorgerà che là si trovano dati interessanti sull'origine di questo termine come sinonimo di rosso.
Per di più, penso che molte volte le domande interessanti o che generano un certo dibattito forniscano idee per nuove domande e questo lo può anche provocare una domanda con un'auto-risposta.
Non sto mica suggerendo di riempire il sito con questo tipo di domande e non tutto si considera come una buona domanda: certe domande con auto-risposta sono state criticate su questo sito in passato, come per esempio  questa (tuttavia, la risposta è stata ben accolta). Devo dire, però, che anche questa domanda è stata utile per me, cioè, mi ha fatto imparare una parola che non conoscevo.
Penso che l'esempio della domanda di @DaG nel link che ho messo all'inizio e anche quello della domanda di @NicolaSap rendano bene l'idea su quello a cui voglio riferirmi. E credo sinceramente che scrivere di tanto in tanto contenuti come questi post  potrebbe arricchire il sito
e che voi italiani potresti fare questo in modo ottimo.
Non cerco neanche di fare che nessuno senta l'obbligo di postare questo né nessun altro tipo di domande: rispetto profondamente la libertà di tutti gli utenti del sito.
Siccome c'è stata certa confusione sull'argomento, aggiungo qui un paio di link:

documentazione sulle auto-risposte del Help Center,

post sulle auto-risposte nel blog di Stack Exchange.


Ecco un estratto dalla risposta alla domanda su Meta.SE "How does accepting an answer work?", che ha ottenuto un ampio consenso da parte della comunità:

Eventually you'll resolve the problem or find a work-around (which may be, "This won't work, so here's what I did instead"). Please add an answer with this information and accept your own answer so that others with your same question can see the path you eventually followed. This is also applicable if no one answer helped you, but you instead combined information from multiple answers.


Insomma, modo di dire del giorno: il piano è che "ce la cantiamo e ce la suoniamo".

@FedericoPoloni Hai colto in pieno l'andazzo!

@FedericoPoloni: Non sto suggerendo di riempire il sito con questo tipo di domande, semplicemente voglio dire che questo si può fare di tanto in tanto, e, secondo me, può dare luogo a contenuti interessanti. In altri siti SE le domande con auto-risposta si vedono e, in genere, sono ben accolte.

@Charo Puoi farmi qualche esempio? Nella mia esperienza, le domande con auto-risposta spesso su SE vengono fatte per rispondere a dubbi frequenti, a mo' di "FAQ" o (per usare un termine più popolare su Stack Exchange) "canonical question". Usarle come dici tu, invece, secondo me renderebbe questo sito più simile a un blog e (per me) molto meno interessante.

@FedericoPoloni: Il sito sarebbe simile a un blog se tutte le domande fossero di questo tipo e, come ho già detto, non è quello che intendevo con questa risposta.

@FedericoPoloni:  In particolare, a me piacerebbe molto vedere questo tipo di domande (e, ovviamente, anche domande senza auto-risposta) fatte da voi italiani. Domande-risposte del tipo, ho avuto la curiosità di sapere tale cosa sulla mia lingua, ho stato cercando e ho trovato questo e quest'altro. E magari altri utenti aggiungono altre cose sull'argomento e la cosa diventa ancora più interessante.

@FedericoPoloni: Ecco alcuni esempi, ma se ne possono trovare di più:   https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3184/,      https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27857/, https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31686/, https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32946/,  https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19665/,  https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17874/,  https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35026/,  https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24414/,  https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35055/,  https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29197/, https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9590/.

@Charo Auto-risposte equivalgono a imposizioni cammuffate del tipo "prima non sapevo che..., ma ora lo so" il che presuppone che gli altri siano interessati ai monologhi di chi scrive. Non mi sembra questo sia il senso del sito. Per questo ci sono rubriche in diversi giornali che di solito si chiamano "Lo sapevate che?".

Perché no? Qualcuno ha avuto la curiosità di sapere quale fosse l'origine del termine "scarlatto" come sinonimo di "rosso", ha stato cercando e non ha trovato nulla, quindi pone la domanda e immaginiamo che altri utenti la trovino interessante. Ma se questo utente ha trovato qualcosa, pone la domanda lo stesso e spiega quello che ha trovato, allora la domanda non intereserebbe più a nessuno?

@Charo A me, e credo ad altri utenti, il percorso che hai compiuto tu per curiosità interessa meno di meno. Non siamo in un sito per monologhi, ma per domande.

@Nico Che ti piaccia o no le auto-risposte sono esplicitamente incoraggiate da SE. Aggiungerò riferimenti ed esempi quando torno a casa ed ho un computer ma fatte in moderazione secondo me sono un eccellente componente del sito.

@DenisNardin Come ha scritto Federico, le auto-risposte sono poco interessanti: Se poi voi obbedite ai dettami di SE, fate pure. Ti cito anche Federico sopra: " Puoi farmi qualche esempio? Nella mia esperienza, le domande con auto-risposta spesso su SE vengono fatte per rispondere a dubbi frequenti, a mo' di "FAQ" o (per usare un termine più popolare su Stack Exchange) "canonical question". Usarle come dici tu, invece, secondo me renderebbe questo sito più simile a un blog e (per me) molto meno interessante". Per cui rispondi anche a lui nello stesso modo invece di indirizzarti solo a me.

@Nico: Ho fatto quell'esempio perché è una domanda che ho visto posta (non da me, da un altro utente) su un'altro sito dedicato a un'altra lingua (sulla traduzione di "scarlatto" a quella lingua) e che altri utenti (non soltanto io) hanno trovato interessante.

@DenisNardin che le auto-risposte siano "esplicitamente incoraggiate da SE" non è certo al 100%. E' vero che spiega che non sono vietate e che anzi in alcuni casi sono più che benvenute, ma tutte le volte che posti una autorisposta il sito stesso ti chiede "Sei sicuro di volerti auto-rispondere?". E' come dire: vanno bene le autorisposte, ma valuta caso per caso.

@FedericoPoloni: I do not want to insist on this discussion because it seems to me that it has been the origin-excuse of a terrible war, but of course I'm not suggesting to produce low quality questions. Do you think that the example of self-answer I gave in this answer is low quality? I was trying to say that I would like to see questions as this one written by Italians from time to time.

@FedericoPoloni: I was not referring to you. You have expressed your opinion in a respectful constructive way, so it's OK.

@FedericoPoloni:  Si veda questo commento, scritto dal moderatore di Spanish.SE:   https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/34714/qu%c3%a9-significa-darse-un-escorpi%c3%b3n-en-m%c3%a9xico#comment62213_34714: "aquí animamos a que la gente se responda sus propias preguntas para crear más contenido" = qui incoraggiamo le persone a rispondere le proprie domande per creare più contenuti.

@FedericoPoloni: Questa recente domanda su Italian.SE è un esempio di quello a cui mi riferivo in questa risposta. A quanto pare, la domanda è stata ben ricevuta sul sito.

@Charo La domanda mi sembra ragionevole; l'auto-risposta è a +3/-2 voti, quindi "ben ricevuta" mi sembra un po' eccessivo. (Precisazione: non sono tra quei downvoter.)

@FedericoPoloni: Ho scritto la "domanda è stata ben ricevuta", non la risposta  (mi è veramente difficile di capire perché, però, si veramente si vota valutando il contenuto e non per altre ragioni). Qui si discuteva di proposte di possibili tipi di domande da fare da italofoni.

@FedericoPoloni:  E, secondo me, neanche questo dovrebbe essere un problema. Ho avuto un dubbio, ho stato ricercando e credo di aver trovato una risposta. Posto la domanda e anche la risposta. Alcuni utenti valutano che la risposta non è buona (con un commento spiegando il perché sarebbe molto meglio) e così me n'accorgo che la mia risposta non era tanto buona come credevo. E, per di più, ricevo altre risposte migliori o più complete. Qual è il problema?

Uno dei problemi sicuramente è che non stiamo aggiungendo contenuti di grande valore, se la risposta è qualcosa che ho saputo trovare da me in pochi minuti appena mi è sorto il dubbio. Quando arrivano domande "vere", perlomeno, è perché c'è una persona che non sa rispondere.

@FedericoPoloni: Veramente non possiamo sapere per quanto tempo è stato l'OP ricercando la risposta se si è scritta con la volontà di dare un'auto-risposta. E può darsi che questo sia così perché su altri siti SE le auto-risposte sono incoraggiate (vedi, per esempio, i link alla fine di questo post).

@Charo Se l'OP stava cercando la risposta da anni, perché non ha scritto la domanda prima? Non sono convinto da questi ragionamenti, mi spiace; non credo che tu ci possa fare molto.

Aggiungo qualche altro esempio: https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14901/,   https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/4750/.

Parole o espressioni colloquiali in conversazioni informali
Nella discussione generata a proposito di
questa domanda si è menzionato che le conversazioni informali sono di solito infarcite di parole, modismi e espressioni colloquiali e che questo fatto spesso difficolta la comprensione da parte dei non madrilingue italiani, persino quando hanno un buon livello di italiano. Anche su questo argomento mi sembra che spesso i meglio adatti per porre domande siano gli stessi italiani: gli stranieri frequentemente non riusciamo neppure a capacitarci su cosa si è detta o non abbiamo l'opportunità di ascoltare tali conversazioni: è difficile porre una domanda su un'espressione che non si è capita o di cui non si conosce l'esistenza.
Si può chiedere sull'origine, sull'uso, sul significato... di questi termini o espressioni. E, secondo me, si può chiedere anche quando se ne sa già qualcosa (so perfettamente che alcuni utenti di questo sito non approvano questa idea).

Alcuni esempi tratti da Spanish.SE, anche se ce ne sono molti in più (in castigliano, mi dispiace): https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/33168/, https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/33094/,
https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22864/, https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14750/,
https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13656/,  https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3148/, https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28931/, https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/35354/.

A suo tempo mi era sfuggita questa proposta. Ne capisco e ne apprezzo il senso, ma temo che le curiosità e i dubbi che può avere un italofono sulle espressioni di cui parliamo siano diversi o addirittura complementari rispetto a quelli di uno straniero che impara l'italiano.

Capisco perfettamente cosa vuoi dire, @DaG, e so che hai ragione. Ma il fatto di porre una domanda di questo tipo (chiedendo sull'origine di un'espressione, su quando si è cominciata a usare, ecc: vedi gli esempi di domande su Spanish.SE nel mio commento: soltanto una è da un non madrelingua) dà l'opportunità a un straniero di sapere dell'esistenza di tale espressione. E questo straniero può a sua volta porre una domanda se, per esempio, non sa in quali contesti si può usare tale espressione (questo accade nell'esempio di domanda su Spanish.SE fatta da un non madrelingua).

E anche di tanto in tanto (soltanto di tanto in tanto) si può anche porre una domanda con auto-risposta, come, per esempio, questa. (So perfettamente che alcuni utenti di questo sito non approvano questa idea, ma ancora non capisco del tutto bene perché. Non ho visto su altri siti SE utenti che si oppongano in questo modo alle auto-risposte, ma certamente non li frequento tutti). A proposito, siccome si tratta di un regionalismo, neanch'io conoscevo quella parola. Quindi, questa domanda con auto-risposta su Spanish.SE è anche stata utile per me.

Penso che sia difficile per un italiano fare una domanda che sia interessante per chi sta imparando l'italiano. Ci sono espressioni che usiamo abitualmente e a cui non facciamo particolarmente caso. Una persona che sta imparando l'italiano può notare assonanze o similitudini tra espressioni che per noi non sono correlate. Domande su quelle espressioni sono accettabili, ma per essere "genuine" dovrebbero essere domandate da chi ha dubbi.

Non sono d'accordo, @kiamlaluno: tutte le domande che ho messo come esempio nel mio primo commento a questa risposta, quella che ho messo come esempio nel commento alla risposta "regional" e alcune di quelle che ho messo come esempio di auto-risposta in uno dei commenti sono domande poste da ispanofoni: per me sarebbe interessantissimo avere domande simili a queste poste da madrelingua italiani. Su Spanish.SE ce ne sono tante e invece su Italian.SE non si vedono quasi mai!

Delle domande indicate nel tuo primo commento, 4 sono sull'etimologia di una parola ed una domanda è su differenze regionali; solo una di quelle domande è stata risposta dalla persona che ha fatto la domanda. Domande sull'etimologia potrebbero essere fatte anche da italiani, ma personalmente non farei domande sull'etimologia di una parola se non ho motivo di farlo. Altrimenti, finirei col riempire il sito di domande sull'etimologia di parole semplicemente per scrivere domande.

Non so molto di spagnolo e non posso fare paragoni, ma penso che sia più facile che sia un italiano che sia confuso da una frase come "lo siento mucho" che uno spagnolo. Non si può dire che, visto che un tipo di domande è frequente in un sito su una lingua, allora lo stesso tipo di domande dovrebbe essere più frequente in un sito su un'altra lingua. Ci sono domande che hanno senso se domandate in un sito, ma non nell'altro sito, a causa delle differenze tra lingua e lingua.

Mi sono imbattuto in questa discussione, ravvivata da poco, e ho pensato che un contributo potevo provare a darlo, anche se non è mia intenzione, in futuro, spendere molto tempo su questo sito. Sono pigro, peculiare, e non ho molto tempo.
Scrivo questo con il sincero intento di aiutare, ma non voglio perderci le notti - per cui, se qualcuno non apprezza, lo prego di ignorare semplicemente quanto avrà letto, e mi scuso in partenza per avergli fatto perdere tempo. Può essere che io ripeta cose già dette o già scartate in precedenza, non ho avuto tempo di leggere tutto.
Per rendere il sito più attrattivo e utile, e invogliare a usarlo di più, si potrebbe considerare alcune cose.
Postare le proprie domande in inglese, quando possibile. Un sito come questo probabilmente interessa più a uno studioso che studia l'italiano ma non lo padroneggia molto, che a uno che ce l'ha come lingua madre.
Fare attenzione ai downvote e ai commenti, specie se diventano lunghe discussioni. A chi pone domande non fa piacere deviare dal fulcro del suo problema. Questo vale anche per le risposte: un sito di domande e risposte con molte risposte criticate non presenta bene.
Attenzione a rispondere alle proprie domande. Io che frequento il sito da pochi giorni sono rimasto perplesso nel vedere molte domande con "autorisposta". Alcune, mi pare, contenevano una autorisposta precedente a quelle di altri utenti. Ma rispondere a sé stessi dopo che qualcun altro l'ha fatto può essere perfino peggio: può dare l'idea di voler correggere, o insegnare come vanno fatte bene le risposte. Non è per niente che il motore del sito chiede
"sei sicuro di volerti autorispondere?"
Un'altra impressione che ho ricevuto dai pochi giorni di esplorazione è una certa severità sul fatto che occorra citare le fonti. Io trovo che nel citare le fonti ci possano essere anche lati
negativi:
Una risposta che recita: "Come riportato dal Garzanti [LINK], il significato è blablabla [sostanzialmente una ripetizione di ciò che dice la fonte]" può dare la vaga impressione di dire: "Vedi, la fonte è lì a disposizione di tutti, ma io l'ho trovata, e tu no. Io sono più bravo di te, la prossima volta cerca meglio, io ho anche altro da fare".
Una risposta come quella di prima può anche dare l'impressione di non riportare alcunchè di originale, ragionato, o per lo meno diretto a chi ha posto la domanda.
La severità sul citare le fonti invoglia a non postare risposte ma commenti, e uccide il confronto e la discussione. Un sito dove non ci sono opinioni personali, esperienze dirette, fresche, idee che
non discendono direttamente da libri colti scritti magari secoli fa, è un sito palloso. Può essere anche interessante leggere una risposta che cita dieci fonti diverse, mi è successo leggendo l'articolo della Crusca a proposito delle trasmissioni di cucina, ma alla fine ho cominciato a essere impaziente perchè la conclusione era sfumata. Se io chiedo a un grande esperto "questa cosa, secondo te, è bella o brutta", mi aspetto che me lo dica, con tatto -volendo-, ma non ho piacere che la sua grande cultura venga sfoggiata per dirmi "caio dice che è bella, tizio dice che è brutta, sempronio è critico con i primi due".
Io ho idee mie, certamente controcorrente e possibilmente sbagliatissime, riguardo al citare le fonti, che esulano perfino da quanto ho detto prima. Il mio ragionamento è il seguente: chi fornisce una risposta ha piena responsabilità di ciò che scrive, anche se cita fonti. Le fonti potrebbero essere sbagliate per diversi motivi, e la responsabilità, giustamente, ricade su chi le fonti le ha scelte. Citare una fonte senza aggiungere del proprio significa anche dire "non posso avere torto, lo dice lui" (e mi ricorda un certo ipse dixit in voga nel medio evo). Una cosa è certa, se si cita per esempio il Garzanti: che il Garzanti non è l'unico a pensarla a quel modo. Indiscutibile.
Poi, quando la fonte è giusta, se si aggiunge qualche cosa - fosse pur solo una traduzione in inglese a beneficio del richiedente,
si ricade, estremizzo, nello stesso problema: qual'è la fonte che certifica che la traduzione, l'interpretazione, l'aggiunta, la chiosa, siano corrette?
A mio modo di vedere, le fonti sono indispensabili per giustificare i presupposti di un ragionamento, non il ragionamento stesso, affinchè si possa ricostruire tutto il percorso logico. Ora, la linguistica ha meno bisogno di ragionamenti di altre scienze, mi sembra, e non vorrei che le mie parole fossero interpretate come una filippica contro le fonti: voglio solo dire che le fonti non sono tutto.

Ti ringrazio per il tuo contributo come sono anche molto grata a tutti quelli che partecipano qui, sul sito Meta, se lo fanno con spirito costruttivo. Detto questo, ho votato negativamente questa risposta perché non sono d'accordo con le idee che hai espresso qui (e perché non rispondi la domanda), ma, per favore, linuxfan, non è niente di personale. Non ho mai votato positivamente o negativamente né qui né sul sito principale seguendo il criterio di se un utente mi risulta o no simpatico. E, secondo la mia esperienza, di solito gli altri utenti di questo sito non votano seguendo questo criter

Ecco la FAQ for Stack Exchange sites in cui si può trovare, tra altre cose, i motivi per votare positivamente o negativamente.

Ho letto parte della FAQ e alcuni post collegati anche prima che me lo segnalassi tu. Comunque ho riletto. E' evidente che le sfumature di certe politiche vengano considerate diversamente da te e da me. Il tuo tono da maestrina m'infastidisce anche se condito da un "ti ringrazio per il contributo", che forse meriterebbe un +1 che bilancia il -1, ma che invece io intendo come "no grazie, provaci ancora". Il risultato è che la mia voglia di contribuire scema ulteriormente. Comunque ti ringrazio per il tempo perso e a mia volta ti rispondo "no grazie, la mia opinione non cambia di una virgola".

Today Italian.SE graduated (i.e., in Stack Exchange jargon, it was promoted to a SE instance without the "beta" label), based on the longevity, number and quality of questions and other parameters.
And yet the number of questions per day is still (apparently) critically low.

So Stack Exchange's actions show that the current number of questions per day is not considered problematic, despite what that Area51 page says.

The Area51 page is known to be very outdated. I think it's been recognized for a while that the consistency of the quantity of the questions is more important than the sheer number (I personally think we are having problems in that direction as well, but we seem to be generating questions nonetheless).

Do you mean that the stats are outdated, or the criteria?

The criteria, sorry if that wasn't clear.
